# Search field loses focus

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to create a search field and to do so I followed [this tutorial](https://codeburst.io/create-a-search-pipe-to-dynamically-filter-results-with-angular-4-21fd3a5bec5c), which shows how to create and use filter pipe.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if(!items) return [];
    if(!searchText) return items;
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
return items.filter( it => {
      return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
   }
}
```

```
<mat-menu #accountsMenu="matMenu">
  <div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
    <mat-form-field>
      <span matPrefix><mat-icon>search</mat-icon></span>
      <input
        matInput
        [formControl]="accountSearch"
        placeholder="search text goes here"
      />
    </mat-form-field>
    <button
      *ngFor="let c of accounts | arrayFilter: accountSearch.value"
      mat-menu-item
      (click)="selectAccount(c)"
    >
      {{ c.Name }}
    </button>
  </div>
</mat-menu>
<div
  [matMenuTriggerFor]="accountsMenu"
>
  Click to show menu
</div>
```

The filtering works, however search field loses focus. I've tried to use trackBy since it was adviced by some sources, however it didn't work for me.

Update: I've found that when I remove 'mat-menu-item' from button, input does not lose focus, but I need it. What should I do it?

Update 2: reproduced issue is available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wymkir)

Comment: You need to reproduce the problem using some of the online editor apps like stackblitz or something else. I cannot help you if you dont reproduce the problem. Also, you should inform us that you are using angular material. 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: mat-menu-item on button must be placed inside <mat-menu></mat-menu> tag and needs to be called with an external button with [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu". Reference here: https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview

Comment: @ThemistoklisBogiatzoglou It is placed inside mat-menu tag. I've added link for stackblitz in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please provide us a sample of code to repoduce the problem?

I have followed the instructions of the tutorial and everything seems to working correctly.

Check working example [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urcckd)

**UPDATE**:

The problem was at

```
<button mat-menu-item...
```

There was an issue on focus input field when using **mat-input-item** attribute on button.

If you replace the **mat-input-item** with the **mat-button** focus will remain from now on.

**Updated example** [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5nwju7)

Comment: I've updated my question to match more to my actual code

Comment: Thank you for the reproduce link, i have updated my answer aswell.

Comment: may also be solved by adding `class="mat-menu-item"` and removing `mat-menu-item` as an attribute... i.e. `<button class="mat-menu-item">`

Answer (score 0):

Various workarounds worked, but UX was getting out of the window, too. I had to ensure the keyboard navigation after the search worked fine. So, I applied a workaround that now fixes the UX completely-

**First thing-** I kept using `mat-menu-item`. Then, modified search input element-

```html
<mat-form-field [subscriptSizing]="'dynamic'">
    <input matInput placeholder="Search"[formControl]="searchControl"
           #searchInput (blur)="onBlur(searchInput)"
           (keydown.arrowDown)="arrowUpDownPressed = true"
           (keydown.arrowUp)="arrowUpDownPressed = true"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

The method-

```js
/**
 * MatManu tries to (maybe a bug) automatically focus the new rendered menu item when we do a search.
 * Because of that, it automatically loses focus while typing in the search bar.
 *
 * This method is patching that behaviour to make it UX-friendly.
 * @param inputElement
 */
onBlur(inputElement: HTMLInputElement): void {
    // If focus was lost because "up"/"down" arrow key was pressed
    if (this.arrowUpDownPressed) {
        this.arrowUpDownPressed = false;
        // Then let is loose the focus
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise focus it again
    inputElement.focus();
}
```

And the tip- The first menu item container which contained the search input, added - `(focus)="searchInput.focus()"` and now it works best-

https://capture.dropbox.com/6h8lQg4RB8RN4sD5